# ARM : How to override U-Boot interrupt vector table

Tags: arm, interrupt, u-boot, texas-instruments

Currently, I'm working on a beaglebone black and I'm trying to implement interrupts.

To launch my program, I'm using U-boot, and I load my binary to the 0x80000000 address.

But, even if I've defined my Interrupt Vector table at the beginning of the RAM (adress 0x80000000), when an interruption occurs, like a "data abort", the interruption isn't caught by my interrupt table, but by the U-boot table. So, for example, I can't call my "data_abort" function when this interruption occurs...

Do you know a way to solve this ? For example to move the address of the Vector table or to rewrite this table ?

Comment: My interrupt vector table is available here :
https://github.com/OS-Project/OnlyOS/blob/alan/kernel/interrupt.s

Comment: Overwrite the U-boot vectors, wherever they are (assuming not in flash, which they shouldn't be as U-boot normally relocates itself to RAM); or use high vectors; or set VBAR appropriately; or turn the MMU on to map whatever you want under whatever vector address is in use... Many possibilities, depending on how you want to play it. Realistically, you're going to want to read the ARMv7 Architecture Reference Manual and get an understanding of how the architecture works to have much hope of getting system-level stuff right on an A-class core.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've find a way. I've moved the adress of vector table by means of the coprocessor :).